# Удаление одинаковых элементов двух векторов. Попадаю в SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, vector

```
void eraser (int tmp, vector<int>a,vector<int>b){
    a.erase(find(a.begin(),a.end(),tmp));
    b.erase(find(a.begin(),a.end(),tmp));
}
```

Comment: Опечатка уровня "детский сад": "я скопировал, а исправить забыл". Такие вещи надо уметь находить самостоятельно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А не попадаете ли вы туда, когда `tmp` нет по крайней мере в одном из двух векторов?

Тогда вы пытаетесь удалить итератор `.end()` - т.е. элемент, которого нет в векторе.

Вот что пишут [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

*The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus* **the end() iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as a value for pos.**

Т.е. удалять `.end()` категорически противопоказано.

О мелочах типа того, что вы удаляете `tmp` **из копий** векторов, писать нужно? Или о том, что из вектора `b` вы пытаетесь удалять элемент вектора `a`?

Comment: Я понимаю что делаю ошибки, очевидные для более опытных людей. За этим и пришёл на SO.  Не за готовым кодом, а за указанием на ошибки, и где прочитать. Сейчас я передаю векторы через & и проверяю наличие элемента итераторами, , но для входных данных типа 
3 1
4 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
возвращается 
3 1
4 2
2 2
3 0
4 0

Comment: Вы сформулируйте задачу точнее. Что вы хотите? Просто одновременно удалять из двух векторов по одному конкретному числу? Потому что почему вы влетаете в неприятности - понятно, но чтоб понять, **как** вам надо поступать, нужно понять, **что** вам, собственно, нужно...

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы проходя оба вектора до конца, если элемент вектора b больше элемента в b, то удалить все эти элементы как из b, так и из a. В конце получим либо два пустых вектора, либо одинаковые значения. Пробовал проходить циклом, передавая элемент в tmp, но вывод не похож на правду. Видимо нужно эту переменную как-то связать с двумя векторами, но я хз как.

Comment: *"если элемент вектора b больше элемента в b"* - это как? И, откровенно говоря, я так ничего и не понял из вашего пояснения. Допустим, вы описались, и "если элемент вектора b больше элемента в a". Какого элемента? в той же позиции? Максимального? Любого? Какие "все эти элементы"? Понимаете, в 90% случаев, когда вы формулируете задачу правильно и недвусмысленно - тут же самому становится ясно, как ее решать. У вас пока ощущение, что вы сами не очень понимаете, что хотите...

Comment: Описался. Больше элемента в а. В той же позиции. b[i]>a[i]. Если b=4, а=1, то мы удаляем единицу из обеих векторов.

Comment: Вообще фигня. А если a = 1 1 1 1, B = 4 4 4 4 - то что делать? Ну нет в b единиц! И что получится? А если b= 4 1 3 1 - какую из единиц удалять? Давайте так - наверное, это у вас часть какой-то большей задачи. Может, расскажете ее? а то у вас чем дальше в лес, нем непонятнее...

Comment: ну вообще да. Это задача 1/4 финала am icpc в Запорожье. Никто её не решил. Суть задачи в том, что есть два числа, первое - количество участников (если введено 4, то дальше в две команды будут записываться числа от 1 до 4, номера участников),  второе - количество пар участников. Известно, что команда а сильнее чем b. Нужно вывести количество возможных победителей и их номера в возрастающем порядке.. По  моей задумке, пары сравниваются, и меньшее число удаляется полностью из двух векторов, а счётчик участников уменьшается на 1. В конце останется 2 числа в первом векторе, счётчик равен 2.

Comment: К такому я пришёл, смотря на входные/выходные данные. Возможно, есть более лёгкий и очевидный способ решения..

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, у вас во втором случае поиск делается по `a`, а удаление - из `b`. Даже если этот поиск что-то действительно найдет в `a`, все равно удалять из `b` по итератору, указывающему в `a` - это неопределенное поведение.

Код, очевидно, писался методом копи-пэйстинга. Но подправить скопированное вы забыли.

Во-вторых, у вас векторы передаются в функцию *по значению*. То есть если даже вы и успешно удалите из них все, что хотите удалить, все равно это никак не повлияет на фактические аргументы функции. Если это - полный код функции, то такая функция бессмысленна.